# Restrict default fields from being set manually in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I recently got into sequelize. The problem is after creating the CRUD operations on a model, I realized that the **id** filed can be set 'manually'.

For example:

```js
export default Article extends Model {}
Article.init({
    title: {type: DataTypes.STRING, unique: true, allowNull: false,},
}, {sequelize, modelName: 'article'});
```

In this case the Article will have the following fields:

```js
{
    id: number;
    title: string;
    updatedAt: Date;
    createdAt: Date;
}
```

Creating a new article where **id** field is present will be set into database and not automatically. My question is, it is possible to restrict the default fileds from being set manually?. I know that I can remove them myself but I'm curios if there is something in the library able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specified on your model if it has a primary key:

```js
export default Article extends Model {}
Article.init({
    myCustomId: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true,},
    title: {type: DataTypes.STRING, unique: true, allowNull: false,},
}, {sequelize, modelName: 'article'});
```

And when you add a new article, you can set the `myCustomId` value:

```js
//...
const article = new Article({ myCustomId: 1023, title: 'aTitle' });
//...
```

Of course, if there is a same `myCustomId` with value `1023` on your DB, an error will occurs.

Comment: In the case of the default field **id**, it is set automatically by the AUTO INCREMENT rule. If a new article is inserted where the id is set, let's say id:4000, the library could ignore it and insert the article in the database and the id will be set by it's default rule, in our case the next count, let's say 8. It's this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if you ever got an answer for this but i have been looking to solve the same problem. The way i have come up with for the moment is to have all my primary keys called ID, and manually deleting 'id' from all create requests.

In the router where the request is received, i have:

```
delete req.params.id
```

This means even if an id is provided by the user, it never even makes it to the controller as part of the request.

Not sure if this is a good (or secure) way to do it, but im just starting out and its the best i have at the moment.